# Can you be charged if police say you sold drugs to a person with no video of the sale

Tags: criminal-law, evidence

Can an individual be charged with selling an illegal substance if they are not in possession and/or have not received money for an illegal substance?

Is video evidence required for such charges?

Comment: Your question title and body say two different things

Comment: Do you imagine that evidence sufficient to convict before the invention of video suddenly became insufficient after its invention?

Answer (score 6):

> can an individual be charged with selling an illegal substance if they are not in possession or received money for an illegal substance

Yes. Testimonies, affidavits, receipts, fingerprints, and circumstantial evidence might conclusively establish that the individual engaged in illegal activity.

Comment: I'd take affidavits out of this list, but it's otherwise correct.

Comment: @bdb484 "*I'd take affidavits out of this list*". See [*Blackledge v. Allison*, 431 U.S. 63 n.25 (1977)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1977494431us631493) ("*When the issue is one of credibility, resolution on the basis of affidavits can rarely be conclusive, but that is not to say they may not be helpful.*", citations omitted). This suggests that affidavits are permissible as long as their role in a criminal conviction is nothing more than supplementary to other evidence.

Comment: I don't agree. Blackledge is about a plea hearing; the affidavit wasn't used as evidence of wrongdoing because there was never a question about the defendant's guilt.

Comment: On second reading, I see the affidavit is actually being used in the context of a habeas petition, making it even further removed from the determination of guilt or innocence. At least in the United States, an affidavit is basically never going to be allowed, as a constitutional matter.

Comment: @bdb484 "*At least in the United States, an affidavit is basically never going to be allowed, as a constitutional matter.*" If anything, I was underrating in my previous comment the role of affidavits. In [*U.S. v. Wilson*, 732 F.2d 404, 413-414 (1984)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19841136732f2d40411061) the court concluded that the use of an affidavit was not error in a case where the affidavit [played a critical role in the jury's guilty verdict](https://www.leagle.com/decision/20031090289fsupp2d80111004).

Comment: Note that you don't need to "conclusively establish" that the crime happened in order to *charge* the suspect. The threshold is lower than that (e.g. "realistic prospect of conviction" [in England and Wales](https://www.cps.gov.uk/publication/code-crown-prosecutors))

Comment: @JBentley "*you don't need to "conclusively establish" that the crime happened in order to charge the suspect.*" Of course. My point is that since evidence can lead to a more stringent outcome (i.e., conviction), charging the suspect on the basis of that evidence is definitely not far-fetched.

Comment: That's definitely an interesting outlier, and the bizarre circumstances help explain why the court did not follow the general rule in that case. But isn't citing *Wilson* sort of like citing *Korematsu*? The relevant law today is completely different than it was when *Wilson* was decided.

Comment: Oh, and reading the other comments now, I see we may just be talking about different stages of the proceeding. If we're talking about establishing probable cause sufficient for charges, then definitely yes, affidavits are the gold standard. If we're talking about "conclusively establishing" guilt at trial, affidavits are basically never allowed.

Comment: @bdb484 "*If we're talking about "conclusively establishing" guilt at trial, affidavits are basically never allowed.*" I just showed you an appellate decision affirming their admissibility. "*isn't citing Wilson sort of like citing Korematsu?*" Not clear what you mean but [*Korematsu v. U.S.*, 584 F.Supp. 1406, 1414 (1984)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19841990584fsupp140611812) reads "*When the parties are in agreement [...] the court need not make as searching an inquiry as when notice on admissibility is disputed*", whereas def. Wilson always disputed the admissibility of the affidavit.

Comment: @bdb484 "*The relevant law today is completely different than it was when Wilson was decided.*" [*U.S. v. Wilson*, 289 F.Supp.2d 801 (2003)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/20031090289fsupp2d80111004) is from year 2003 and it nowhere reflects (not even as *obiter dictum* or in footnotes) that the law has changed --let alone that it is "completely different-- in this regard.

Comment: Would you expect otherwise? Judges aren't usually expected to drop footnotes predicting future changes in the law.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Judges aren't usually expected to drop footnotes predicting future changes in the law.*" Nobody here is expecting judges to "predict future changes in the law". It is just not unusual for court opinions to point out when the law *has* changed. As of the ruling from 2003 it appears that the law had not changed in the way you purport. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129043/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-bdb484).

Comment: Right. The law changed *after* 2003.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Right. The law changed after 2003.*" Then citing your sources for that assertion would have been more productive than bringing up the inapposite & much earlier *Korematsu*, making me look into it, and leading to an extended discussion on this side topic. SE is already asking us to "avoid extended discussions in comments", which is why you need to click on the chat link if you are genuinely interested in discussing your hitherto unsupported assertion.

Comment: That's OK. I already learned this law, and I know you're hostile to correction. My comments are more for the benefit of OP and other readers.

Comment: @bdb484 "*I know you're hostile to correction. My comments are more for the benefit of OP and other readers.*" I am not against being corrected, but you have to do that with accurate, verifiable sources if you expect the OP, me, or other readers to take your assertions any seriously. Barely saying "*The relevant law today is completely different*" or "*I already learned this law*" just doesn't cut it. That vagueness does not benefit the audience at all, and instead it only reinforces the impression that you got nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question in the title, there is no requirement for video evidence showing a person selling drugs to prosecute for unlawfully making such a sale. Other evidence, such as witness testimony, perhaps by an undercover officer, can be sufficient. When available, such video evidence is often persuasive and likely to be used.

To answer the question in the body, depending on the specific statute which a person is charged with violating, there may need to be evidence of the receipt or promise of money or some other thing of value paid or to be paid to the accused or someone associated with the accused.

For example, if Bob transfers heroin to Alice in return for a promise that Alice's associate Gail will deliver money to Bob's associate John, that is probably enough to convict Bob (and probably John) if there is evidence to show this, and to show that both Bob and John knew what they were selling. The exact proof needed will depend on the specific statute involved, which will depend on the jurisdiction. The evidence needed to prove the elements of the offense will be evaluated by the trier of fact (Judge or Jury).